# tslib: mouse cursor moves in the opposite direction to selection box

Tags: xorg, xfce, touch-screen

I'm using tslib/xf86-input-tslib on an ARM box with Debian 7. **ts_calibrate** and **ts_test** are working properly. The problems occur in Xfce. When I touch the screen and move the finger, I see, that mouse cursor is following my finger, but a selection box occurs with some offset to the Y-axis and then moves towards mouse cursor. My xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "tslib"
    Driver "tslib"
    Option "Device"    "/dev/input/event1"
    Option "ScreenNumber"  "0"
    Option "Width" "0"
    Option "Height"    "0"
    Option "Rotate"    "NONE"
    Option "EmulateRightButton"    "1"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
     Identifier      "Default Layout"
     InputDevice     "tslib" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

tslib version is 1.1 and xf86-input-tslib from Ubuntu: https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/xf86-input-tslib/saucy

An USB mouse is working as expected.

cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0000 Product=fe2e Version=0100
N: Name="TPS6507x Touchscreen"
P: Phys=1-0048/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/omap/omap_i2c.1/i2c-1/1-0048/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000003
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that Xorg used both evdev and tslib driver for the same device.

Standard Xorg configuration files scan input devices and if it is a touchscreen, then evdev will used by default:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

Xorg seems not to check, if device is already used with another driver. That's why it used both drivers. The solution was to comment this section in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`.